# postgreSQL COPY TO is producing a corrupted file

Tags: postgresql

```
COPY sqllearning.superstore_people

TO 'C:\Windows\Temp\sup_people.csv'

WITH DELIMITER ','

CSV HEADER;
```

When I open the csv file either in notepad or excel I get an Error that says:

> Excel cannot access 'file.csv', the document may be read only or encrypted.

> file.csv cannot be accessed. the file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read- only

Any tips on how to resolve this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't write into the `c:\Windows` folder (or any folder below that). It's protected for a good reason.

Comment: What is your database encoding? What encoding does that Excel program expect?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue before. I solved it by checking and setting ownership of the entire folder and all its subfolders and files for current user (in Windows - right click on the folder - properties - security). Maybe it would help for you also

Comment: I think you're correct but I'm having issues now with editing permissions in my windows folders so I can't 100% confirm that this is the answer. for some reason that's the only folder my postgreSQL can save data which is weird. Thanks definitely helpful.